# MySql encoding hell

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, unicode, utf-8

I've had a website running for almost 20 years, unfortunately I made the mistake of not aligning the HTML character set with the MySql character set, so all of my data seems to be double encoded (I think) or possibly mojibaked, or both. Perhaps one of you experts can clear this up for me.

Before I go on, you should know that I'm intending to upgrade to tomcat 9 HTML5 with UTF8 characters and emojis

```
With page pageEncoding="UTF-8"  at the top of each page
request CharacterEncoding set to "UTF-8"
response CharacterEncoding set to "UTF-8"
and ContentType set to "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

The new MySql database version 8 (latest version) has been set up and sits on the same machine.
The current (LIVE) MySql version which contains all records is version 5.6.19.

[This is a small set of records that I see in workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNHwV.png)

This is the above table's setup:

CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`txt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

[MySql 5.6 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmzLx.png)

All of these currently render perfectly on a webpage.
Here is the rendering of the above nonsense data and its byte array representation on a page...

```
    REC = don’t go breaking my heart
    Bytes: 64 6f 6e ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffff99 74 20 67 6f 20 62 72 65 61 6b 69 6e 67 20 6d 79 20 68 65 61 72 74 fffffff0 ffffff9f ffffff98 ffffff9b

    REC = 
    Bytes: fffffff0 ffffff9f ffffff98 ffffff8d 20

    REC = Haha...... 
    Bytes: 48 61 68 61 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 20 fffffff0 ffffff9f ffffffa4 ffffffa4 fffffff0 ffffff9f ffffffa4 ffffffa4 fffffff0 ffffff9f ffffffa4 ffffffa4

    REC = Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit
    Bytes: 4d 69 74 74 65 6c 65 75 72 6f 70 ffffffc3 ffffffa4 69 73 63 68 65 20 4e 6f 72 6d 61 6c 7a 65 69 74

    REC = Středoevropský letní čas
    Bytes: 53 74 ffffffc5 ffffff99 65 64 6f 65 76 72 6f 70 73 6b ffffffc3 ffffffbd 20 6c 65 74 6e ffffffc3 ffffffad 20 ffffffc4 ffffff8d 61 73

    REC = 中国标准时间
    Bytes: ffffffe4 ffffffb8 ffffffad ffffffe5 ffffff9b ffffffbd ffffffe6 ffffffa0 ffffff87 ffffffe5 ffffff87 ffffff86 ffffffe6 ffffff97 ffffffb6 ffffffe9 ffffff97 ffffffb4

    REC = Центральная Европа летнее время
    Bytes: ffffffd0 ffffffa6 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd0 ffffffbb ffffffd1 ffffff8c ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd1 ffffff8f 20 ffffffd0 ffffff95 ffffffd0 ffffffb2 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffbe ffffffd0 ffffffbf ffffffd0 ffffffb0 20 20 ffffffd0 ffffffbb ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 20 ffffffd0 ffffffb2 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffbc ffffffd1 ffffff8f

    REC = Иркутск стандартное время
    Bytes: ffffffd0 ffffff98 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffba ffffffd1 ffffff83 ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd1 ffffff81 ffffffd0 ffffffba 20 20 ffffffd1 ffffff81 ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffb4 ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffbe ffffffd0 ffffffb5 20 ffffffd0 ffffffb2 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffbc ffffffd1 ffffff8f

    REC = heure d’été d’Europe centrale
    Bytes: 68 65 75 72 65 20 64 ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffff99 ffffffc3 ffffffa9 74 ffffffc3 ffffffa9 20 64 ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffff99 45 75 72 6f 70 65 20 63 65 6e 74 72 61 6c 65

    REC = توقيت برازيليا الرسمي
    Bytes: ffffffd8 ffffffaa ffffffd9 ffffff88 ffffffd9 ffffff82 ffffffd9 ffffff8a ffffffd8 ffffffaa 20 ffffffd8 ffffffa8 ffffffd8 ffffffb1 ffffffd8 ffffffa7 ffffffd8 ffffffb2 ffffffd9 ffffff8a ffffffd9 ffffff84 ffffffd9 ffffff8a ffffffd8 ffffffa7 20 ffffffd8 ffffffa7 ffffffd9 ffffff84 ffffffd8 ffffffb1 ffffffd8 ffffffb3 ffffffd9 ffffff85 ffffffd9 ffffff8a

    REC = เวลาอินโดจีน
    Bytes: ffffffe0 ffffffb9 ffffff80 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffa7 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffa5 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffb2 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffad ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffb4 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffff99 ffffffe0 ffffffb9 ffffff82 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffff94 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffff88 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffffb5 ffffffe0 ffffffb8 ffffff99

    REC = heure normale d’Afrique de l’Ouest
    Bytes: 68 65 75 72 65 20 6e 6f 72 6d 61 6c 65 20 64 ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffff99 41 66 72 69 71 75 65 20 64 65 20 6c ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffff99 4f 75 65 73 74

    REC = Центральная Америка летнее время
    Bytes: ffffffd0 ffffffa6 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd0 ffffffbb ffffffd1 ffffff8c ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffb0 ffffffd1 ffffff8f 20 ffffffd0 ffffff90 ffffffd0 ffffffbc ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb8 ffffffd0 ffffffba ffffffd0 ffffffb0 20 20 ffffffd0 ffffffbb ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd1 ffffff82 ffffffd0 ffffffbd ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 20 ffffffd0 ffffffb2 ffffffd1 ffffff80 ffffffd0 ffffffb5 ffffffd0 ffffffbc ffffffd1 ffffff8f

    REC = Ora de vară a Europei de Est
    Bytes: 4f 72 61 20 64 65 20 76 61 72 ffffffc4 ffffff83 20 61 20 45 75 72 6f 70 65 69 20 64 65 20 45 73 74
```

As you can see, the data is readable ... on a UTF8 webpage and on an old Windows-1250 webpage too ... but is unreadable by anything else, I've googled this to death, and have tried all of the information I found on various sites. And yes I've seen Rick James document, but none of his suggestions work for me.

I've tried all combinations of convert and cast that I can think of
Example of the most popular one:
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(txt USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING UTF8) AS res FROM test;

It successfully decodes 'Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit', but all other records become NULL.

I've also tried java's decoders
byte[] utf8Bytes = rec.getString("txt").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String result = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");

**result** displays good on a webpage, but If I write result to a file or send **result** to my new database, it becomes garbage again.

```
donâ€™t go breaking my heartðŸ˜›
ðŸ˜ 
Haha...... ðŸ¤¤ðŸ¤¤ðŸ¤¤
MitteleuropÃ¤ische Normalzeit
StÅ™edoevropskÃ½ letnÃ­ Äas
ä¸­å›½æ ‡å‡†æ—¶é—´
Ð¦ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ð°Ñ Ð•Ð²Ñ€Ð¾Ð¿Ð°  Ð»ÐµÑ‚Ð½ÐµÐµ Ð²Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ
Ð˜Ñ€ÐºÑƒÑ‚ÑÐº  ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð´Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾Ðµ Ð²Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ
heure dâ€™Ã©tÃ© dâ€™Europe centrale
ØªÙˆÙ‚ÙŠØª Ø¨Ø±Ø§Ø²ÙŠÙ„ÙŠØ§ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø³Ù…ÙŠ
à¹€à¸§à¸¥à¸²à¸­à¸´à¸™à¹‚à¸”à¸ˆà¸µà¸™
heure normale dâ€™Afrique de lâ€™Ouest
Ð¦ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ð°Ñ ÐÐ¼ÐµÑ€Ð¸ÐºÐ°  Ð»ÐµÑ‚Ð½ÐµÐµ Ð²Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ
Ora de varÄƒ a Europei de Est
```

As you can see, I ought to be able to retrieve the data, but have not found a way yet.

Can someone please help me solve this?

Remember, all I want to do is either write the unicode data in its properly rendered form to a file, or send the unicode data in its properly rendered form to my new database.

Comment: Never mind, I think I've solved it.

Comment: I was writing the data to a txt, but when I opened the file the file with notepad I get...

First line: donâ€™t go breaking my heartðŸ˜›

But I then changed the file extension to .htm and open it again with notepad...

First line: don’t go breaking my heart 

So, it is writing the data correctly. I just didn't realise it at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that nobody these days posts actual helpful solutions, I thought I'd buck the trend.

If you ever experience this problem and want to extract double encoded data and write it to a dump file (like a csv file or sql file) using java8, try this as a starter to your project...

```
// Create and fill a list of maps called recs
// Note: BaseMap is just my own class that extends Map, it has extensions like getString, getInt, etc
// I'm using column called "txt" to store some UTF8 test data

Path path = Paths.get("/my/file/name/here"); // <<< change this
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

    for(int i=0; i<recs.size(); i++)
    {
        BaseMap rec = new BaseMap((Map)recs.get(i));
        try {
            byte[] doubleEncodedBytes = rec.getString("txt").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            String decodedTxt = new String(doubleEncodedBytes, "UTF-8");
            writer.append(decodedTxt);
            writer.newLine();
            // If you don't want to write to a file, 
            // you could instead execute on a connection to Database 2: INSERT INTO `schemaname`.`tablename` (columns...) VALUES (" decodedTxt ",....)
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    writer.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Yes it's a slow solution, but all the MYSQL solutions that I've read and tried failed, so it's my "final solution" so to speak

Comment: Notes about migration from one database to another: I've now successfully converted all of my data without any errors. If you want to migrate to a 2nd database (in my case, I migrated data from MySql 5.6[UTF8] to MySql 8[UTF8MB4]), I simply created a string called sqlString which contained "insert into...." and I just converted it to UTF8 and executed it using statement.execute. like so: String sqlUTF8 = new String(sqlString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"); statement.execute(sqlUTF8);

Answer (score 0):

For Emoji, you must use MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  The best way is to establish that during the connection.  Second best is via `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`.

```
SELECT UNHEX('646f6ee2809974207274f09f989b');
```

yields

```
don’t rt
```

Does it for you?  BUT -- Use `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see what is in `col`; the data may have been mangled *before* your code to display hex.

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('dâ€™Europe' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);
yields   d’Europe   mojibake to ut8 (or utf8mb4),
```

For more debugging, do

```
SELECT LENGTH(col), CHAR_LENGTH(col), col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

If it is double-encoded, we can detect it from the two different lengths.

You show the `CREATE TABLE`, but what about the code that loaded the data?  And the code that dumped it?  Or did you upgrade in place?  My point is that the mojibake (etc) could have happened during the upgrade.

```
SELECT LENGTH('d’Europe'), CHAR_LENGTH('d’Europe'), 'd’Europe', HEX('d’Europe');
+----------------------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------+
| LENGTH('d’Europe')   | CHAR_LENGTH('d’Europe')   | d’Europe   | HEX('d’Europe')      |
+----------------------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------+
|                   10 |                         8 | d’Europe   | 64E280994575726F7065 |
+----------------------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------+
```

The "double-encoded" hex would be

```
64C3A2E282ACE284A24575726F7065
```

This shows the optimal(?) way to undo it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('64C3A2E282ACE284A24575726F7065') USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('64C3A2E282ACE284A24575726F7065') USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| d’Europe                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I glanced over the other rows you provided; they seem to be consistent with each other.  That is, the fixes that make one of them work will apply to the others.  (Be sure to check one with an Emoji.)

**More**

It's a toughie.

> Here's the first row from `SELECT HEX(col)` `'646F6EC3A2C280C2997420676F20627265616B696E67206D79206865617274C3B0C29FC298C29B'`
> for `don’t go breaking my heart`

Let me start on the "right single quote" (`’`) since it seems representative.

```
Char   UTF-8              If interpreted as latin1
’      E28099             â€™
â€™    C3A2 C280   C299      You have this
â€™    C3A2 E282AC E284A2    Correct encoding
```

Something turned `€` into `C280`.  While the reverse works "correctly", it is not the valid UTF-8 mapping.  I don't know where that happened; I doubt if it is was inside MySQL.  Was the mapping done in some client?

As we see from this, MySQL does not want to use the `C280`:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(UNHEX('C3A2E282ACE284A2') AS char), CAST(UNHEX('C3A2C280C299') AS char);
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| CAST(UNHEX('C3A2E282ACE284A2') AS char) | CAST(UNHEX('C3A2C280C299') AS char) |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| â€™                                     | â                                 |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

So, I don't see an easy way *in mysql* to clean up the mess.  It is, however, rather straightforward to turn `C280` into `80`.

If you can somehow get the *string* `donâ€™t` and then feed the *string* back into MySQL, plus a CONVERT expression, you may be able to fix it.

Until a decade or so ago, `C280` was part of a trick that hackers used to slip naughty things past browsers.  But the browsers got wise.

If you can find where the `C280` came from, please file a security bug report with the software.  And stop using it.

If it was in MySQL 20 years ago, you may have been using `latin1` in version 4.0 (where there was no other character set) or 4.1 improperly converted from latin1.  Or maybe still using latin1, but with UTF-8 characters simply sitting across 2-3 latin1 characters.  At that point, the wrong `ALTER` leads to "double-encoding", but you may not have noticed it since the mangling during `INSERT` is mostly undone during `SELECT`.

MySQL 5.5 (late 2010) introduced utf8mb4 which could correctly handle Emoji.

(Meanwhile, the Emoji looks like the same hacked double-encoding.)

Comment: Re: Does it for you?
YES

And re: utf8mb4
Yes, I understand that... now. I just didn't understand that 15 years ago when I modified my DB

Comment: Re: SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('64C3A2E282ACE284A24575726F7065') USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)
This works as a test case, but doesn't work in a real world scenario. If you substitute unhex(...) with say a column name unhex(hex(`txt`)), you get NULLs, or if you substitute unhex(...) with just `txt` you get NULLs.
This is the very reason why I gave up on using CONVERT & CAST in the first place

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` -- specifically doing the conversion to hex for display inside the MySQL server.

Comment: Here's the first row... '646F6EC3A2C280C2997420676F20627265616B696E67206D79206865617274C3B0C29FC298C29B'

Comment: I'm guessing you can't solve this either, Rick

Comment: Thanks for trying Rick, but MySql was never going to be able to achieve what I needed all by itself.